# How to turn on Location Detection on iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, location

By a mistake, when asked for location in iphone simulator, I tick into the condition to remember my choice and then select "Now Allow". And now, my app cannot get any location in simulator. I tried to clean the app, then delete in simulator and reinstall it, then quit everything and restart my computer. The app never asks me for my location again, it just throws error. Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto System preferences -> Security -> click on Reset Warnings (click on the lock first to make changes).

Answer (score 0):

In simulator there is an option to reset the simulator. Have you given it a try?